# NORMAL copula vs Frechet copula

Tags: math, statistics

I would appreciate if anyone could explain the difference and provide an example to generate 2 random variables with a given Rank correlation Ps .
Thanks

Comment: For an explaination about the difference you should ask at https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you will post it there.